# Pandas dataframe filter with matching

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have following data frame

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['as,df','as.df'])
>>> df
       0
0  as,df
1  as.df
```

I would like to filter above dataFrame using string with exact match except for the  case. I tried following way but it is not able to differenciate between `.` and `,`

```
>>> df[0].str.match('^As.df+$', case=False)
0     True
1     True
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

Can you please help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a backslash to *escape* the `dot`: `'^As\.df+$'`.

```
>> df[0].str.match('^as\.df$', case=False)
0     True
1    False
Name: 0, dtype: bool
```

To see when (and how) to escape *special characters* in regex, see this question: [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)

---

If the regular expression is not under your control, then you can use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) before adding some characters yourself to make sure that no accidental dots, square brackets or other special characters make it to the string being searched.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It helps partially. But I do not have control on the string to be searched for, So I cannot manually edit the string apart from adding regex characters at the beginning and end of the string. Some times the search string could 42.1.1.p4 or 42,1,1.P4 etc., To follow your suggestion, I must edit the string first by replacing . in the at everyplace string with \.

Comment: @user26249 Updated the answer. Use `re.escape` before adding `^`, `+`, '$`', etc.

Comment: Thanks. That answers my question.